# How to build query? Any idea?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

3 tables:

**Mark table:**

```
student_id sa_id marks
1           1    75
1           2    80
1           3    100
2           4    85
2           5    90
2           6    60
```

**course table:**

```
course_code    sat_id    name_code
AAA 100          1        midterm1
AAA 100          2        midterm2
AAA 100          3        final
BBB 200          4        midterm1
BBB 200          5        midterm2
BBB 200          6        final
```

**transform table:**

```
sa_id     sat_id
1            1
2            2
3            3
4            4
5            5
6            6
```

```
select course.course_code, mark.marks 
from mark  
  left outer join transform on transform.sa_id = mark.sa_id
  left outer join course on course.sat_id = transfrom.sat_id
where course.name_code = 'midterm1'
```

At the above query only midterm1 result, also we can extract mid2 and final

```
select mark.student_id,course.course_code, mark.marks, course.name_code 
from mark 
  left outer join transform on transform.sa_id = mark.sa_id
  left outer join course on course.sat_id = transfrom.sat_id
order by mark.student_id, course.course_code
```

**Result will give:**

```
student_id course_code  marks name_code
1           AAA 100      75     midterm1 
1           AAA 100      80     midterm2
1           AAA 100      100    final
2           BBB 200      85     midterm1
2           BBB 200      90     midterm2 
2           BBB 200      60     final
```

So how to build query that should be

```
student_id   course_code   midterm1   midterm2  final
1             AAA 100       75          80       100   
2             BBB 200       85          90       60
```

Comment: @scaisEdge why you use max? Is it important to use?

Comment: It is important, because you must group by `student_id`. Whenever you group, in the `SELECT` you can only group by the columns you have in the `GROUP BY`, otherwise you must use aggregate functions like `MAX()`. You know that each group will have only one column, but Oracle doesn't know that and it would complain (give an error) if you didn't use aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when , group by (and a fake aggregation function)

```
select 
      student_id
    , course_code
    , max(case when name_code ='midterm1' then mark else null) midterm1
    , max(case when name_code ='midterm2' then mark else null) midterm2    
    , max(case when name_code ='final' then mark else null) final
from mark
left outer join transform on transform.sa_id = mark.sa_id
left outer join course on course.sat_id = transfrom.sat_id
group by  student_id, course_code
order by mark.student_id, course.course_code
```

But if you don't like  aggregation functio  you can use  a 3 seleft join on mark

```
  select 
        mm1.student_id
      , mm1.course_code
      , mm1.mark  midterm1
      , mm2.mark  midterm2
      , mm3.mark  finale    
  from mark as  mm1 
  left join mark as mm2 on mm1.student_id = mm2.student_id and mm1.course_code = mm2.course_code
  left join mark as mm3 on mm1.student_id = mm3.student_id and mm1.course_code = mm3.course_code 
  left outer join transform on transform.sa_id = mm1.sa_id
  left outer join course on course.sat_id = transfrom.sat_id
  where mm1.name_code = 'midterm1'
  and mm2.name_code = 'midterm2'
  and mm3.name_code = 'final'
```

Comment: But i need use without max, it is not properly use where

Comment: @jaraisyn   the max(..)   is a dummy function used only to take advantage of the grouping capabilities based on GROUP BY, which in this case enable you to get a single row for each relationship between the values (otherwise you would have as many lines as the corresponding relationships) ..: so it's a dummy function that does not produce collateral damage but that allows you to reduce the number of resulting rows

Comment: yeap , i know that you are talking about but student don't know which term and year this marks. if we add 'where' will show error

Comment: @jaraisyn  if you want filter an aggregation function you should use having   not where (and without alias ) eg: having  max(case when name_code ='midterm1' then mark else null) > 50;

Comment: but if we use for example where course.year = 2015 and course.term = 2, how should be? if you answer i will be thankful and without max in no way?

Comment: For  course.year = 2015 and course.term = 2,   you can use where, is only for aggreated cresult taht you should use ahving ... but anyway  I have update my answer with also a solution based  on self  join ... hope is useful ..

Comment: can you check in table so mm1.course_code it will be course.cod_name? error again )))

Comment: There was  a mark and i have change  in mm1 .. and for course_name  there isn't course_name in your question .. what are you  referring ..?  i think this is two proper  solution if you want undestand ..